# Data Model for One To Many - Itemcontainer in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

i have two CFs "ItemContainer" and "Items".

I used to have a secondary index in "Items" referring to the "Itemcontainer".
Something like:

```
CREATE table items (key uuid primary key, container uuid, slot int ....
CREATE INDEX items_container ON items(container)
```

i change the "container" cell quite often when changing the itemcontainer.
Documentation says that a secondary index shouldnt be used in this case.

So i tried something like:

```
 primary key(container, key)
```

in items. now i can query all items for an itemcontainer just fine.
but how do i put the item in another itemcontainer?
you cant override parts of the primary key.
so do i really have to delete the item and reinsert all the date with a different "container" field?

Doesn't this create a lot of tombstones?
Also "Items" has like 20 columns with maps and list and everything...

any ideas?